# EC2 Django App Only Accessible without www. prefix

Tags: django, configuration, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

**if I visit:**
myapp.com (it works)

**if I visit:**
www.myapp.com (throws http 500 error)
or
the fully-qualified version: http://www.myapp.com  (throws http 500 error)

that http 500 error is:

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Oct/2013:18:33:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 460 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
```

I am getting this error, from my `access.log` used as part of my nginx configuration (note `error.log` has nothing new in it):

```
server {
        #listen       8001;
        listen       80;
        #listen 127.0.0.1;
        server_name     myapp.com  www.myapp.com;               #*.myapp.com;
        #server_name ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/;

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/static/;
            #alias /static/;
            #root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

my **ec2 security policy** looks like:
[image: img]

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: What do the Django logs say?  Have you checked the [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/) setting?

Comment: Yes ALLOWED_HOSTs I've tried hardcoding for example: .myapp.com, http://www.myapp.com, www.myapp.com as values. I also had tried *.myapp.com . But it doesnt allow it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't appear to be a problem with any settings as much as it was an issue with `settings.py`, the settings from `settings.py` weren't being applied because I didn't:

1) Stop Gunicorn and Stop Nginx first
2) Then start them up again using proper commands like:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/gunicorn_config.py myapp.wsgi; sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf;
```

Special thanks to user **Steve** above for the point out.

If anyone runs into a problem like this where your app is accessible via `<domainhere>.com`, but not `www.<domainhere>.com` in the future check the following:
1) Make sure your `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[]` has settings like:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.myapp.com','myapp.com','<server-ip-here>','ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com']
```

2) That you are properly starting both gunicorn and nginx using commands like:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/gunicorn_config.py myapp.wsgi; 
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf;
```

3) Use a command like this to check that both are properly running:

```
ps ax|grep nginx; ps ax|grep gunicorn;
```

Good luck!